# Access table INSERT not working through VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, vba, oledb

I'm writing a program in VB and trying to insert into the DB (which I've done before), but it's not working. Assuming that all the parameter values are correct, what would cause no exceptions or errors to be raised, but a row to not be inserted with the code below?

```
Dim sqlString As String = "INSERT INTO ArDetail (ArType, ArTenantNbr, ArInvNbr, ArSeqNbr, ArTransactAmt, ArAmtDue, ArChkNbr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
Dim sqlArgs As String(,) = {{"@ArType", "RI"},
                    {"@ArTenantNbr", lblTenantNumber.Text},
                    {"@ArInvNbr", row.Cells("Inv Nbr").Value.ToString},
                    {"@ArSeqNbr", nextSeqNbr.ToString},
                    {"@ArTransactAmt", row.Cells("Paid Amt").Value.ToString},
                    {"@ArAmtDue", "0"},
                    {"@ArChkNbr", txtCheckNumber.Text}}
```

I'm attaching this so you can see the information in sqlArgs as it goes in.
[image: Error screenshot with object explorer on sqlArgs]

**EDIT: It was asked that I include the `ChangeTableObj()` code**

---

```
Public Shared Sub ChangeTableObj(ByVal sqlString As String,
                                 Optional ByVal sqlArgs As String(,) = Nothing)

Dim i As Integer

'Instantiate Access database Connection using Connect string in app.config
Dim dbConnObj As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
dbConnObj.ConnectionString = My.Settings.TenManDBConnectionString

'Instantiate an OleDb Command Object using the Connection object
Dim cmdObj As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlString, dbConnObj)
cmdObj.CommandType = CommandType.Text

'Add requested parameters to the sql command if given
If Not sqlArgs Is Nothing Then
    For i = 0 To sqlArgs.GetUpperBound(0)
        cmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue(sqlArgs(i, 0), sqlArgs(i, 1))
    Next i
End If

'Open connection, update database, and close

cmdObj.Connection.Open()
cmdObj.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmdObj.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Where's the code that actually performs the insert?

Comment: @MattGibson I'll attach it right now.

Comment: I have to ask....  Is your connection string correct?  Are you looking at the expected table in the correct database?  Perhaps the rows are being inserted into a different copy of the database?

Comment: Yes it works. I've been able to select data just fine with it. I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: if you check the return value of `cmdObj.ExecuteNonQuery()` it's 0?

Comment: I would suggest you run a simple test like 'insert into xxx (A, B, C, ...) values 1, 0, 0, ...'  where you avoid all references to your form fields / cells. If that runs, then you can narrow down the culprit. Also, you may want to generate the full SQL statement and display so you can take a look at it.

Comment: And more importantly please attach the connection string as well.